# Updating from user based configuration file

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil, gcloud-cli

Whenever I run a bq or gsutil command, I get the below output:

```
Loading user based configuration file: [/home/reggie/.config/gcloud/properties].
User based configuration files are deprecated and will not be read in a future gcloud release.
```

What is the alternative, and how do I go about using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few months ago, we introduced gcloud 'configurations' which allow you to have multiple sets of `gcloud config` properties that you can switch between.  More information on the topic can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations

The next time you set a property using `gcloud config set` your legacy config file will be automatically upgraded to a new named configuration and you should stop seeing that message.  You can also use

`gcloud config configurations create` to create a new named configuration.

Comment: Thanks; running gcloud config set core/disable_color true worked.

Comment: I solved this by opening C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\properties, seeing what property I had set, and doing `gcloud config set <property-name> <property-value>`.

Comment: @Mark any reason the workspace files aren't supported anymore? Historically speaking text files are timeless, easy to use, and integrate with various tools (you can commit them to version control, easily view them, etc) The most important advantage being that if you're in a project's directory, they apply, and if you're not, they don't. What advantage does this new system have exactly? Because of how it works I now have to build extra tools just to "hide it" to make sure my colleagues don't accidentally forget to switch the names around on the 10 projects their working on and cause a disaster.